# How do I check to make sure form fields are not empty strings?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my validateForm() method to make sure email is valid (which I have done) and also make sure the 'name' and 'comments' fields are not empty. For some reason I cannot get the second part down, and need some assistance. Here is the current code I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
}
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Empty Fields");
    return false;
}
}
// -->
</script>
```

And the form:

```
<form name="myForm" action="http://webdevfoundations.net/scripts/formdemo.asp" onsubmit="return      validateForm()"  method="POST">
Your name: <br>
<input type="text" name="name" ><br>
<br>
Your email: <br>
<input type="text" name="email"><br>
<br>
Your comments: <br>
<textarea name="comments" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Formatting your code properly shows that you have a couple of syntax errors there. Or is it just a typo?

Comment: `if (x == null)...` should be written within `validateForm() {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using same variable for both field `name` and `email`. It doesn't make sense.

There is one more syntax error in your code i.e. You have put an extra `}` before checking second condition. So it makes that condition outside of that function

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
    if (x == "" || y == "") {
          alert("Empty Fields");
          return false;
       }
}
```

So here is [JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XzzuD/)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning both the form fields to the variable `x`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way:

```
    function validateForm(){
        var x=document.forms["myForm"].getElementsByName('email').value;
        var y=document.forms["myForm"].getElementsByName('name').value;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length){
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
        }
        if (y==null || y==""){
           alert("Empty Fields");
           return false;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should opt below points to keep in  mind for above code

(1) validation for Empty fields should come first then Email checking.
(2) As per the code, your Empty field logic is not a part of validateForm()  (It might be typo),so when validationForm() method will called,this logic won't execute
(3) you should write return true at the end of method validateForm()
(4) Use different variable names of field checking

GO through above points,it will be helpful to solve your Issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

First there are syntax error in your code. It seems that there are two redunant curly braces. And then you assign both the two fields to x, and only the name field get its value. Also, you'd better first check the email field empty or not and then operate on it. Finally I don't think your check for email is right. For example: xxx@a.info. So you may try:

```
function checkEmail(aEmail){
    var pattern=//w+([-+.']/w+)*@/w+([-.]/w+)*/./w+([-.]/w+)*/; 
    var objExp=new RegExp(pattern);
    if(objExp.test(str)==true){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    if (x == "" || y == "") {
        alert("Empty Fields");
        return false;
    }
    if (!checkEmail(y)) {
        alert("Not a valid email");
        return false;
    }
}
```